# Python 3: Determine if object supports IO

Tags: python, interface, python-3.x

Some Python methods work on various input sources.  For example, the XML element tree `parse` method takes an object which can either be a string, (in which case the API treats it like a filename), or an object that supports the IO interface, like a file object or `io.StringIO`.

So, obviously the `parse` method is doing some kind of interface sniffing to figure out which course of action to take.  I guess the simplest way to achieve this would be to check if the input parameter is a string by saying `isinstance(x, str)`, and if so treat it as a file name, else treat it as an IO object.

But for better error-checking, I would think it would be best to check if x supports the IO interface.  What is the standard, idiomatic way to check if an object supports a specified interface?

One way, I suppose, would be to just say:

`if "read" in x.__class__.__dict__: # check if object has a read method`

But just because `x` has a "read" method doesn't necessarily mean it supports the IO interface, so I assume I should also check for every method in the IO interface.  Is this usually the best way to go about doing this?  Or should I just forget about checking the interface, and just let a possible `AttributeError` get handled further up the stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python strongly encourages duck typing: Just assume the object that was passed in is valid and try to use it.  This way, your code is as flexible as possible.  Of course, if the actions of your code depend on the type of the object that is passed in, you do need some kind of type checking.  I suggest to keep this type checking to a minimum though, and go for `isinstance(x, str)`.

If you pass in an object that neither is a string nor supports an IO interface, this will result in an `AttributeError`.  If this happens, this is a bug in the calling code.  This exception shouldn't be handled anywhere -- instead the bug should be fixed!

That said, you *could* use

```
isinstance(x, io.IOBase)
```

to test for the built-in classes supporting the I/O protocol.  This would restrict your code to classes that actually derive from `io.IOBase` though -- a superficial and unnecessary restriction.

Comment: I'd add that checking for the interface doesn't prevent a complying class from not doing what it is supposed to, making the check rather superfluous.

Comment: io.IOBase is an abstract base class, so you shouldn't need to inherit from it for isinstance/issubclass to work

Comment: @gnibbler: You either need to derive from it, or you need to register your own type using `IOBase.register()`.  Still I think this is an unnecessary complication that does not provide much benefit.

Answer (score 1):

> Or should I just forget about checking the interface, and just let a possible `AttributeError` get handled further up the stack?

The general pythonic principle seems to be doing whatever you want to do with the object you get and just capture any exception it might cause. This is the so-called *duck typing*. It does not necessarily mean you should let those exception slip from your function to the calling code, though. You can handle them in the function itself if it's capable of doing so in meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, python is all about duck typing, and it's perfectly acceptable to check for a few methods to decide whether an object supports the IO interface. Sometimes it even makes sense to just try calling your methods in a try/except block and catch `TypeError` or `ValueError` so you know if it *really* supports the same interface (but use this sparingly). I'd say use `hasattr` instead of looking at `__class__.__dict__`, but otherwise that's the approach I would take.

(In general, I'd check first if there wasn't already a method somewhere in the standard library to handle stuff like this, since it can be error-prone to decide what constitutes the "IO interface" yourself. For example, there a few handy gems in the `types` and `inspect` modules for related interface checking.)

Comment: Oh, and if you decide to treat anything that's not a string as an IO object, make sure to use `isinstance(x, types.StringTypes)`, not `isinstance(x, str)`, since `isinstance(u'foo', str)` returns `False`.

Comment: But on second thought, that last caveat doesn't apply to Python 3, so... carry on.

Comment: In Python 2.x, you usually did `isinstance(x, basestring)` to check for `unicode` or `str`.